# True false question regarding algebraic closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{k})$ where $\mathbb{k}$ is an algebraically closed field.

which  of the  following statement  is true/false ?

(A) Every element of $G$ is diagonalizable;

(B) Every element of $G$ is diagonalizable if $\mathbb{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$;

(C) Every element of $G$ is diagonalizable if $\mathbb{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F_p}$;

(D) There exists a basis of $\mathbb{k}^n$ with respect to which every element of $G$ is a diagonal matrix.

My attempts  :  option  b) will be True  every element of $G$, the general linear group of square matrices of order $n$ over some algebraic closed field $\mathbb{k}$, is diagnonalizable if $\mathbb{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

i don't  know the other option

Any hints/solution  will be apprecaited
thanks u

Comment: Jordan normal form may help

Comment: @RichardMartin  im not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The group generated by 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is a finite subgroup of $GL(2,\bar{\mathbb F}_p)$.

Comment: @@Eclipse Im not  getting   option c) and d)  ....  as  i can  discard option 1)    from ur   counter example

Comment: @jasmine This is also a counterexample for c) and d). Here $\mathbb{k}=\bar{\mathbb F}_p$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: still not getting    can u elaborate  more  option c)

Comment: @jasmine c) states that every element of $G$ is diagonalizable. But for $G$ given above, there exists an element that is not diagonalizable, i.e. the generator itself.

Comment: @ Eclispse  sun....  thanks u